# How to make one async db call and save output for subsequent functions?

Tags: javascript, aws-amplify

I am trying to keep db queries to a minimum. The goal is to make *one* query and use data in other functions.  So far, I have this code:

```js
async function GetCoverage(scroll_path) {
  const apiName = "xxxx";
  const path = "/scrolls/" + scroll_path;
  const myInit = {
    headers: {},
    response: false,
  };
  const response = await API.get(apiName, path, myInit);
  console.log("response:", response);
  return response.Items;
}

let dataGlobal;

const getData = async () => {
  const response = await GetCoverage("all");
  dataGlobal = response;
  return response;
};

(async () => {
  await getData();
  console.log("dataGlobal:", dataGlobal);
})();
```

The problem is every `await getData()` invocation drives another db query. How can I avoid that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You basically want a lazily initiated, persistent promise result.

Something like this should suffice...

```js
let dataGlobal;

const getData = () => (dataGlobal ??= GetCoverage("all"));
```

The first time `getData` is called, it will assign the promise returned by `GetCoverage()` to `dataGlobal` and return it.

Any subsequent calls will return the already assigned promise.

---

Here's a quick demo using a fake `GetCoverage`

```js
// mock
const GetCoverage = () => {
  console.log("GetCoverage called");
  return new Promise((r) => {
    setTimeout(r, 1000, Math.random());
  });
}

let dataGlobal;

const getData = () => (dataGlobal ??= GetCoverage("all"));

// Make parallel calls
getData().then(console.log.bind(null, "Result #1:"));
getData().then(console.log.bind(null, "Result #2:"));
getData().then(console.log.bind(null, "Result #3:"));
```

See also [Nullish coalescing assignment (??=)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing_assignment)